# Meson, can it generate "Debug" and "Release" in the same Visual Studio project?

Tags: meson-build

I'm using visual studio solutions (and sometimes batch files) to build my C++ programs, and I'm looking into trying cmake or meson or something else. Is it possible to generate a visual studio project with those tools that have both "Debug" and "Release" builds in it, without them generating two separate projects? Is it possible to, for example, define SOME_MACRO only for "Debug" build?

I did read meson FAQ and quickstart guide, but it didn't answer my question.

Comment: Please, ask about a **single tool**, either CMake or Meson. Those tools have independent set of features.